# Emulating a network switch as software on Linux

Tags: linux, software-rec, switch

I am doing my project on network virtualization on cloud computing. I am going to implement a testbed for the cloud environment and measure the performance of cloud services in a virtualized network.

I need to have a switch that provides L2VPN connection, that is for example three clients connect to each other via this switch but the connection is L2VPN. Now is there any software that could emulate this kind of switch on Linux so I can create the testbed?

Comment: cisco packet tracer or gns3 are the likely first stops.

Comment: however i do not think that gns3 supports any managed switches IOS's.

Comment: it supports one iirc due to the others having diffrent arch., but i *think* the inbuilt one supports l2vpn. might be wrong.

Comment: L2VPN sounds like IPsec over L2TP. A product which implements that is a VPN gateway not a switch. Take a look at Cisco Concentrators or use any other product. Here is a description of various implementations: http://www.jacco2.dds.nl/networking/openswan-l2tp.html